# How make click button in toolbar from different fragment in ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have activity,which have 5 fragments in ViewPager and in toolbar I have made one button and I want to perform click operation on button  differently for selected tab fragment.I have have:

```
usertextView_done= (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.actionbar_tv_icon_done);
```

But it creates the single instance for all fragment or all tab.

Comment: Does this tool bar + button exist at activity?

Comment: yes in activity had both, i am able to access from the fragment but it create single instance for all fragment

Comment: paste code from fragment where you are able to access this button (click code)

Comment: textView_done=(TextView) ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.actionbar_tv_icon_done);
        textView_done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context," Split Amount ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

Comment: Does this toast appear from every fragment when clicked?

Comment: textView_done=(TextView) ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.actionbar_tv_icon_done);
        textView_done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context," Split Amount ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


I have called textView of Activity

Comment: yes, I have written the different toast for different fragment but it call only one

Answer (score 1):

If this toast appears from every fragment when clicked, then you can do following.

-- in your activity

```
public void calledFromFragment(String tag)
{
if(tag.equalsIgnorecase("fragment-1-tag")
{
// TODO : for fragment 1
}
else if(tag.equalsIgnorecase("fragment-2-tag"){
// TODO : for fragment 2
}
.
.
 and so on
}
```

---- in your fragment

```
    textView_done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View v) { 
((Activity)context).calledFromFragment("fragment-1-tag");
});
```

do this for each fragment and let me know.

Comment: Hey sam I have added screen sort of my page ,here Done button is available in toolbar ,and viewPagger have five fragments I want to click dine button from different fragment .

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the button and toolbar exist in the parent activity. 
So here is a simple way to do it:

The idea is to create a static integer in the activity and update it in the fragments with its respective number, this way you can keep track of which fragment is currently visible. 
Example:

```
//in activity class
public static int CURRENT_FRAGMENT = 1; //set this to your first fragment that is being viewed
```

Now, you have to update the integer from each fragment that is resumed.

```
//in each fragment add this code
@Override
public void onResume(){
  ParentActivity.CURRENT_FRAGMENT = 2; //in case you're in fragment 2
}
```

And finally in your activity, add this:

```
//in actvity class
button .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  if(CURRENT_FRAGMENT ==1 ){
    //do things for fragment 1
  } else if (CURRENT_FRAGMMENT ==2 ){
    //do things for fragment 2
  }
etc...
}
```